# Creating a Shopping Cart with Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce

I wish to use paypal to create a shop to an existing site, however I have reached a problem.

Paypal has a facility to 'add to cart' however when clicked on, it goes to their servers.The check out has no customisability what so ever, so looks completely out of sync with my site.

Is it possible to create a shopping cart on PayPal showing the list of items on MY site (so I can customise the look and feel of the shopping cart) and then only when the payment needs to be made, the user is sent to the PayPal Site.

Thanks

NOTE: I'm using pure HTML,CSS & PHP. I am not using a CMS such as WordPress. 
Also when I mean I want to customise the look and feel of the shopping cart, I don't mean just the button, but the way the items is shown up along with details such as Qty.

Comment: don't use the pp shopping cart write\install your own and use pp for payment processing only

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with basic PHP code that you built on your own (no framework like WP) then you'll need to build your own shopping cart.

If you were to use WP, though, you could use WooCommerce which is a great shopping cart system and would probably save you lots of time.